# How to vary stroke or fill color based on (secondary) data property in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm able to draw lines just fine, however when trying to alter line's color based on the data's property `deviationFromAvg`, it only ever returns the first color based on the value at index `[0]`.

How do I vary the line color based on the property `deviationFromAvg`?

```
      // shape of data
      // fooData = Array<{
      //    value: number;
      //    deviationFromAvg: number; 
      // }>

      var leftLine = d3.line()
       .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
       .y(function(d, i) { return y((d as any).value); });

      // this produces a correct length list of {value: fooNumber, deviationFromAvg: fooNumber}
      console.log(deviationFromAvg);

      updateNode.append("path")
      .datum(fooData)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", function(d, i) {

        // logs only once... value: 123, deviationFromAvg: -1
        console.log(d[i]);

        if((d[i] as any).deviationFromAvg > 0)
          return "red"
        else if((d[i] as any).deviationFromAvg < 0)
          return "green";
        else
          return "blue"
      })
      .style("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", leftLine as any);
```

Additionally, if I try something like this, it only ever draws one random color for the whole set of lines each time i refresh:

```
      return rgbToHex(
             Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), 
             Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), 
             Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) 
      );
```

Comment: It seems that you have an array of object where property value is the is the y-value and index is the x-value.  In your data-binding with `datum`, this array will create a single line with a single stroke color.   How are you expecting the single line to have multiple colors?  Do you want a gradient line?  A line where each point is a different color?

Comment: oh, so i'd have to do like attr("x1", (d, i)=> x(i)).attr("y1", (d,i) => d.value) etc. instead of binding to the line?

Comment: In order to answer, I'd need to know what you want the singular line to look like.  Segments between points to be a color based on `deviationFromAvg`?